# Dynamically recreate HTML/jQuery Mobile form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How would I recreate the following jQuery Mobile form dynamically in jQuery? I basically want to try and take up as few lines of code as possible. Anything Ive tried so far ends up about the same length. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <div data-role="page" id="create-person-dialog">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" >
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">                         
                <form id="create-person-dialog">
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <textarea data-theme="b" type="input" id="editFirstName" placeholder="First Name"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                    <textarea type="input" id="editLastName" placeholder="Last Name *"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                        <select id="editSalutation" data-native-menu="false">
                          <option> </option>
                          <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                          <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                          <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                        </select>
                </fieldset>
                    <button href="#" id="edit" data-theme="b" data-role="button">Save</button>  

                    <div id="delete">
                        <button data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" type="button">Delete</button>
                    </div>  
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Heres the beginning of my first attempt, I just create an empty div and start appending...

jQuery:

```
   $('#create-contact-dialog').append("<div id='dataRole' data-role='content'></div>");
   $('#create-contact-dialog #dataRole').append("<form id='create-contact-dialog'></form>");
   $('#create-contact-dialog form').append("<fieldset data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   $('#create-contact-dialog fieldset').append("<textarea data-theme='b' type='input' id='firstName' placeholder='First Name'></textarea>");
```

Comment: For HTML that complex use a template plugin. It will take a lot of code to build that dynamically.

Comment: FYI, append() accept multiple arguments content using comma as separator http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Just decided to whip the whole thing up in regular jQuery and hide it at the bottom of the page.

For anyone who ever needs a big old form...

```
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog')
        .append("<div id='dataRole' data-role='content'></div>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #dataRole')
        .append("<form id='create-contact-dialog'></form>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='fnFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #fnFeild')
        .append("<textarea data-theme='b' type='input' class='reg' id='firstName' placeholder='First Name'></textarea>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='lnFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #lnFeild')
        .append("<textarea data-theme='b' type='input' class='reg' id='lastName' placeholder='Last Name *'></textarea>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='sFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #sFeild')
        .append("<select id='salutation' placeholder='Salutation'></select>");     
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='tFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #tFeild')
        .append("<textarea data-theme='b' type='input' class='reg' id='title' placeholder='Title'></textarea>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='dFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #dFeild')
        .append("<textarea data-theme='b' type='input' class='reg' id='department' placeholder='Department'></textarea>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='accFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #accFeild')
        .append("<textarea data-theme='b' type='input' class='reg' id='account' placeholder='Account'></textarea>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog form')
        .append("<fieldset id='btnFeild' data-role='fieldcontain'></fieldset>");
   jQuery('#create-contact-dialog #btnFeild')
        .append("<button href='#' data-theme='b' data-role='button' id='save'>Save</button>");
```

I populate the select with a function thats called when the dialog is called:

```
        function populateSel(){
         jQuery("#salutation")
         .append('<option value=""></option>')
         .append('<option value="Mr.">bar</option>')
         .append('<option value="Ms."></option>')   
         .append('<option value="Mrs."></option>')  
         .append('<option value="Dr."></option>')   
         .append('<option value="Prof."></option>')        
     }
```